# No directive found with exportAs 'ngForm'. Have tried all suggestions

Tags: angular

I know this question has been asked many times but all the solutions I have found have not resolved my issue. This is my form in the login component html file:

```
 <form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="login()">
            <p *ngIf="errorMessage" class="error">{{ errorMessage }}</p>
            <p class="username">User Name</p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter user name" name="username" [(ngModel)]="model.username">
            <p class="password">Password</p>
            <input type="password" class="centered-items" placeholder="Enter password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="model.password">
            <hr>
            <button class="login-btn" type="submit">Login</button>
            <button [routerLink]="['../']">Cancel</button>
            <p>Not registered? <a [routerLink]="['../register']">Register now</a></p>
        </form>
```

This is my login method in the login component .ts file:

```
 login() {
    this.databaseService.login(this.model).subscribe(() => {
    },  error => {
      this.errorMessage = error.error;
    }, () => {
      this.route.navigate(['../']);
    });
  }
```

This is the error being received in the console:

```
src/app/login/login.component.ts:8:16
    8   templateUrl: './login.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component LoginComponent.
src/app/register/register.component.html:6:27 - error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'ngForm'.
```

I have added the FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule to both my app.module and the login.module files. I have restarted VS code and I have tried running npm update. I have also tried removing the # from #loginForm as one post suggested.

Comment: Did you import FormsModule?

Comment: What is your Angular version?

Comment: I think `#loginForm="ngForm"` should be `(formGroup)="ngForm"`

Comment: it looks like the version I am using is 9.1.7. I have imported FormsModule. Using (formGroup)="ngForm" gives me the error: "Identifier 'ngForm' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member"

Comment: I have updated Angular to version 10 but I still have the same issue

Comment: check the name of your component, the error login.component.ts:8:16 looks like that Angular can not find the login.component.html Maybe is login-component.html? Remember that Angular us "case-sensitive" (It's not the same loginComponent than logincomponent)

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `LoginComponent` to the declarations of the `app.module` file resolved this for me.